# nltk naive bayes train data format

Tags: python, classification, nltk, training-data, naivebayes

The task i want to do is to classifiy Named Entity Recognition with NLTK Naive Bayes. I have my own corpus that looks like this

```
Sementara itu Pengamat Pasar Modal <ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Dandossi Matram</ENAMEX> mengatakan, sulit bagi sebuah <ENAMEX TYPE="ORGANIZATION">kantor akuntan publik</ENAMEX> (<ENAMEX TYPE="ORGANIZATION">KAP</ENAMEX>) untuk dapat menyelesaikan audit perusahaan sebesar <ENAMEX TYPE="ORGANIZATION">Telkom</ENAMEX> dalam waktu 3 bulan.   1
```

I have already extract the entity and the value so it became like this

```
[[('PERSON', 'Dandossi Matram'), ('ORGANIZATION', 'kantor akuntan publik'), ('ORGANIZATION', 'KAP'), ('ORGANIZATION', 'Telkom')], [('ORGANIZATION', 'Telkom')],...]
```

Then i am flatting the list and reversing the value of tuple so the order become like this

```
[('Dandossi Matram', 'PERSON'), ('kantor akuntan publik', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('KAP', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Telkom', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Telkom', 'ORGANIZATION'),...]
```

Because NLTK Naive Bayes need dictionary, so i convert the tuple-list into dictionary.

```
{'Agus': 'PERSON', 'Jawa Barat': 'LOCATION', 'Disney': 'ORGANIZATION', 'City': 'ORGANIZATION', 'manchestereveningnews': 'ORGANIZATION', 'Roma': 'LOCATION', 'PSG': 'ORGANIZATION', 'LPPNPI': 'ORGANIZATION', 'Telkomsel': 'ORGANIZATION', 'Federer': 'PERSON', 'Garuda Indonesia': 'ORGANIZATION',...}
```

An error pop up when i train the classifier

> for fname, fval in featureset.items():
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

It's strange because my data format is in dictionary. Please help me. As for my code, here it is:

```
import re, nltk, random
ner_list = []
with open("ner_corpus.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        #print(line)
        tags = re.findall(r'<ENAMEX\s+TYPE=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</ENAMEX>', line)
        #tags = re.findall(r'<(?:ENAMEX\s+TYPE)=.+?>(.+?)</(?:ENAMEX)>', line)
        ner_list.append(tags)
f.close()
ner_list = [item for sublist in ner_list for item in sublist]
ner_list = list(map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]),ner_list))
random.shuffle(ner_list)
ner_corpus = dict(ner_list)
print(ner_corpus)
splitratio = 0.8
train = ner_list[:int(len(ner_list)*splitratio)]
test = ner_list[int(len(ner_list)*splitratio):]
print(len(train))
print(len(test))
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train)
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test))
```

Comment: Please see this page on what data NLTK requires: http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html And explain in detail about your data.

Comment: thank you for answering. i have already got the answer.